# Error in creating JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm very new to PHP and JSON, so I hope you'll excuse my (probably) stupid question.
I'm trying to create a new JSON with fundamental information for my needings, using the information returned by Google Maps API.
Here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: biagiomontesano
 * Date: 22/10/15
 * Time: 18:16
 */

function selectLongestSteps($steps_txt, $min_meters)
{
    $steps = JSON.parse($steps_txt);
    //$steps = json_decode($steps_txt, true);
    //$steps = $steps_txt;
    echo 'Num of steps: ' . count($steps[0]);
}

function createJsonFromResponse($response_json)
{
    // output json
    $output_json = '[';

    // number of steps
    $num_steps = count($response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']);
    //echo $num_steps;

    // fill the json
    for($i = 0; $i<$num_steps; $i++)
    {
        // start parenthesis
        $output_json .= '{';

        // start latitude
        $output_json .= '"start_lat":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['start_location']['lat'] . ',';

        // start longitude
        $output_json .= '"start_lng":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['start_location']['lng'] . ',';

        // end latitude
        $output_json .= '"end_lat":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['end_location']['lat'] . ',';

        // end latitude
        $output_json .= '"end_lng":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['end_location']['lng'] . ',';

        // step length
        $output_json .= '"step_length":' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['distance']['value']. ',';

        // html instruction
        $output_json .= '"instruction":"' . $response_json['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['html_instructions'] . '"';

        // closure parenthesis
        $output_json .= '}';

        // insert comma if required
        if($i != $num_steps-1)
            $output_json .= ',';

    }

    $output_json .= ']';

    return $output_json;
}

function get_driving_information($start, $finish)
{
    if (strcmp($start, $finish) != 0) {
        $start = urlencode($start);
        $finish = urlencode($finish);

        $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' . $start . '&destination=' . $finish . '&sensor=false';

        // get the json response
        $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

        // decode the json
        $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

        return $resp;
    }

    else
        return null;

}




try
{
    $info = get_driving_information('via Tiburtina 538, Roma', 'via Ariosto 25, Roma');
    $steps = null;
    if(!$info)
        echo 'No info';

    else
         $steps = createJsonFromResponse($info);

    selectLongestSteps($steps, 200);
    //echo $steps;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

As a test, I asked my function selectLongestSteps to display the number of elements in the JSON. 
As you see, I tried to initialise variable $steps in 3 different ways: the last two return a wrong results (0 or 1, while result should be 18).
The first one, that I found on web, returns the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant JSON - assumed 'JSON' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prova_php/create_json.php on line 11

Fatal error: Call to undefined function parse() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/prova_php/create_json.php on line 11
```

I suspect the problem is in creating JSON inside the other function.
Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line:

```
$steps = JSON.parse($steps_txt);
```

JSON.parse() ist a JavaScript function. You need something like this in PHP

```
$steps = json_decode($steps_txt);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: thanks for help.
as you can see from commented code, I already tried this kind od solution, but I get 0 as the number of element in the most external array inside JSON.
maybe it be a problem in creating it, in function createJsonFromResponse, that forbids first function to recognise all the elements inside JSON?

Answer (score 2):

PHP has in-built function to change array to json and vice-verse.

**json_encode($array)** will give json form of array.

**json_decode($json, true)** will give your array back from json. If you didn't give true as your second param, you will be getting an object instead of an array.

Comment: thanks for help.
as you can see from commented code, I already tried this kind od solution, but I get 0 as the number of element in the most external array inside JSON.
maybe it be a problem in creating it, in function createJsonFromResponse, that forbids first function to recognise all the elements inside JSON?